# Keyword not supported. Parameter name: integrated security

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

Hi all I am getting the error as specified when I am trying to retrieve the connection from `App.config` file.

My `App.Config` is as follows

```
<add name="Conn" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SYSTEM19\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Dora;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`
```

At this line of code I am getting the error mentioned can any one help me

```
dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, MyConnectionString);
```

Comment: You appear to be using an SQL Server connection string with a MySqlDataAdapter. Is your database SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: `Roy Goode` good catch even I wonder how I use like that. Any way I fixed it.

Comment: Did you really fix it? It still seems confusing.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it as per `Roy` said I referred to the wrong database

Answer (score 5):

[MySQL Connection String](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Integrated Security is not valid keyword for MySQL connection strings

Comment: I found that `Protocol` is also a problem giving the same error

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue because I was missing the `Initial Catalog=` bit!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because the word Security was on the next line!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Visual Studio 2022 automatically added a comma between `Integrated` and `Security` after I copied and pasted the connection string from another project.  After I removed the comma, everything is working fine.